# How to cut and sort through a pandas column with respect to another column in a separate dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I have two dataframes, both of which have a column called "float_values", among other column that they don't share with each other. I wish to sort through the first dataframe by cutting the both the top and bottom part where the value of the second dataframe can be seen and paired. For example:

df1 has a range of values, from 2000 and onwards with an iteration of 1. df2 has some values, from 1000 and up to 5000, there is however not any real reliable iteration, rather just random jumps. I want to cut df1 where the lowest value and highest value of df2 is. So if the lowest value in df2 is 2015, df1 should be cut in that place. And same thing with the highest value.

I have tried something like

```py
max_value = dataframe2['float_values'].max()
min_value = dataframe2['float_values'].min()
mask = (dataframe1['float_values'] <= max_value and \ 
           dataframe1['float_values'] >= min_value)
dataframe1 = dataframe1[mask]
```

But I get a strange error saying "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Furthermore, what I want to do is analyze the erratic numbers of df2, and see how many values in between the values in df1 that corresponds to, and create chunks of df1. I hope it makes sense. I have tried things like

````
```new_list = []
for i in range(len(range_list)):
new_list.append(i)
divide_chunks(process_data, range_list[i])
x = list(divide_chunks(process_data, range_list[1]))```
````

but I don't think this leads to what I want

Comment: Could you share with us a sample of your input data and the expected output, please?

Comment: There seems a minor error in your code, please check with this: `mask = (dataframe1['float_values'] <= max_value) & (dataframe1['float_values'] >= min_value)`

Comment: @Zygos: did this help you?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work either. I had to write to separate masks and apply them separately

Answer (score 0):

The following with simple data example might do it:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Data example:

```
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame({'float_values':[500,2000,2002,2010,6000]})
dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame({'float_values':[1000,5000]})
```

Build a mask:

```
max_value = dataframe2['float_values'].max()
min_value = dataframe2['float_values'].min()
mask = (dataframe1['float_values'] <= max_value) & (dataframe1['float_values'] >= min_value)
```

Check the result:

```
new_dataframe1 = dataframe1[mask]
new_dataframe1
```